# angularjs formName.$dirty does not work with IE9. <form name="formname" ng-submit="doSubmit();">

Tags: angularjs

```
angularjs formName.$dirty does not work with IE9. I am using 1.2.17.build164 version.
```

here is the form that I am testing, I am not getting the form dirty!!! printed in the page. Same code works fine with firefox and chrome.

```
    <form name="formName" ng-submit="doSubmit();">
    <input type="text" name="firstName"/>
    <span ng-show="formName.$dirty">form dirty!!!</span>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't have model field on the input box:-)

```
<form name="formName" ng-submit="doSubmit();">
    <input type="text" name="firstName" ng-model="hello"/>
    <span ng-show="formName.$dirty">form dirty!!!</span>
    </form>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eeryhd3j/)